# Extend Functionality of Textfields and Textareas at the Same Time

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make a custom `textfield/textarea` where their text get selected when they get focus. Two ideas came to mind:

1- Make **CustomTextField/CustomTextArea** classes that extend their superclasses, and in the constructor of these classes add the functionality i want [example code] :

```
public class CutstomTextField extends TextField implements Customizable {

private boolean recentlyFocused = false;

public CutstomTextField() {
    super();
    customize();
}

/**
 * @Special_Behaviour: Selects all its text when gets focus
 **/
@Override
public void customize() {
    this.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, event -> {
        if (recentlyFocused) {
            event.consume();
        }
    });

    this.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
        // Deselect on focus loss
        if (!newValue) {
            this.deselect();
            recentlyFocused = false;
            return;
        }
        recentlyFocused = true;
        // Select all
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if (!this.getText().isEmpty()) {
                this.selectAll();
            }
        });

        // Delay to avoid issues
        Timeline tl = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.2), event -> recentlyFocused = false));
        tl.play();
    });
}
```

}

> But with this i have to basically copy paste the same code that adds
>   functionality to both CustomTextfield and CustomTextarea

2)

- Make a `CustomTextInputControl` class that extends `TextInputControl`.
- Add the functionality i want.
- and then have the `CustomTextfield//CustomTextarea` **extend** that class.

> But now it seems like i have to copy paste all code of the Textfield
>   class to the CustomTextfield class for this to work. Same for the
>   CustomTextarea class.

In both cases it feels like i'm doing something wrong! So my question is what is the most proper way to achieve what i want?

Comment: Java doesn't do multiple inheritance, so you have few options.  One possibility is to factor out the common code into a separate class, then delegate the work in TextArea and TextField to that class. A little messy but it will result in more code sharing.

Comment: True, if there isn't a cleaner solution i guess i have to stick with the first approach. I'm only adding functionality to 2 classes, so no big deal i guess.

Comment: If you are using java above 1.8 you can move your code to interface default method for multiple inheritance or instead of using anonymus classes extract you code to one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the particular case you have above, you can get the functionality you want without using inheritance at all:

```
public class CustomTextControl {

    private static class BooleanWrapper {
        private boolean value ;
    }

    public static <T extends TextInputControl> T customize(T control) {

        BooleanWrapper recentlyFocused = new BooleanWrapper();

        control.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, event -> {
            if (recentlyFocused.value) {
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        control.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
            // Deselect on focus loss
            if (!newValue) {
                control.deselect();
                recentlyFocused.value = false;
                return;
            }
            recentlyFocused.value = true;
            // Select all
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                if (!control.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    control.selectAll();
                }
            });

            // Delay to avoid issues
            Timeline tl = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.2), event -> recentlyFocused.value = false));
            tl.play();
        });

        return control ;
    }

}
```

Which you use with:

```
    TextField customTextField = CustomTextControl.customize(new TextField());
    TextArea cusomtTextArea = CustomTextControl.customize(new TextArea());
```

If you want to be able to use this with FXML, you need to add some no-arg factory methods:

```
public class CustomTextControl {

    // existing code...

    public static TextField newTextField() {
        return customize(new TextField());
    }

    public static TextArea newTextArea() {
        return customize(new TextArea());
    }
}
```

and then you can do:

```xml
<CustomTextControl fx:factory="newTextField">
    <!-- set text field properties -->
</CustomTextControl>
```

Note that none of this will work if you want to override existing `TextInputControl` methods.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time James. Does the boolean wrapper migrate with the returned control? Meaning can it be used by the control after the control has been instantiated?

Comment: @RafatRefai The listeners retain references to the wrapper, and the listeners use it after the control has been instantiated, but there's no way to access it. Not sure if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Oh so they do retain references to it. Now i know why you used a wrapper. Thank you for the answer!!

Comment: @RafatRefai The wrapper is used because you can only refer to final or effectively final variables in lambda expressions or anonymous inner classes. Since the boolean value itself has to change, it needs to be wrapped inside an object that is only assigned a value once. (If you try this without the wrapper, you'll see that it won't compile.)

Comment: It won't compile even in my example code? Because it did just fine, i wonder why hmm. Still got a long road to learn :)

Comment: @RafatRifaie It compiles in your example code because you use a field (which is appropriate in a subclass). Using the pattern here, a field won't work because you need the method invocation to create a new boolean variable - i.e. you need a local variable, not a field. The rule about final/effectively final only applies to local variables.